# itk library error in python-xy 2.7.10

Tags: python-2.7, itk, pythonxy

I recenlty installed python-xy 2.7.10 and trying to run a simple script using itk fails due to the following error:

> RuntimeError:
>   C:\u\itk-git_b\Modules\Remote\SCIFIO\src\itkSCIFIOImageIO.cxx:274:
>   itk::ERROR: SCIFIOImageIO(0295DBE0): SCIFIO_PATH is not set. This
>   environment variable must point to the directory containing the SCIFIO
>   JAR files

The script I'm running now is simple enough:

```
import itk

pixelType = itk.UC
imageType = itk.Image[pixelType, 2]
readerType = itk.ImageFileReader[imageType]

reader = readerType.New()
reader.SetFileName("./Sand_sample.bmp")
reader.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you enabled `Module_SCIFIO` when configuring ITK with CMake. So you can either disable it, reconfigure and recompile. Otherwise, you can properly set it up. Maybe you need to run `sudo make install` (or build the `INSTALL` target in Visual Studio). Or you could do what the error complains about and set environment variable `SCIFIO_PATH` ([*nix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session), [Win](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)).

You can find more info about SCIFIO in corresponding ITK [class documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1SCIFIOImageIO.html).